# MySQL Left Join not pulling in result

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a MySQL query where i'm trying to lookup a products name in one table from another table based on it's ID as follows:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT product, expirydate, SUM(quantity), status FROM
   stockmovement a LEFT JOIN (SELECT  productid, product AS productname FROM
   products) b ON a.product = b.productid WHERE a.status = '0' GROUP BY 
   a.product, a.expirydate HAVING SUM(a.quantity) > 0 ORDER BY a.product,
   a.expirydate ASC");
```

Everything works apart from the left join which returns blank when i try to output 'productname'. Can anybody see where the query is going wrong?

Thanks in advance and Merry Christmas :)

Comment: You are joining `a.product` to `b.productid`... is that correct?  Without knowing the data, it looks like you'd want `b.product` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing field names. 'product' in the stockmovement table is an ID which i'm trying to join to 'productid' in the products table and pull 'product' which is the products name within the products table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't your query be something like below rather

```
SELECT a.product, a.expirydate, 
SUM(a.quantity), a.status, b.product as productname 
FROM stockmovement a 
LEFT JOIN products b ON a.product = b.productid 
WHERE a.status = '0' 
GROUP BY a.product, a.expirydate 
HAVING SUM(a.quantity) > 0 
ORDER BY a.product, a.expirydate;
```